# Time Plot on X-axis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time, plot, axis

sorry if this question has been asked before.

I'm collecting data from a sensor which gives me a reading every millisecond which gives 864000 readings per 24 hours.

When I plot this I can only get it to show sample number, what I'm looking for is a plot that has every hour shown, for example 13:00:00:00 for 1pm, so every 36000 data points, and when I zoom in between data points I want it to show the exact time at that point, such as 13:25:30:60 etc.

I assume the best way to do this is to create another variable with just time on it and plot my variables against this? Any other ideas would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can have two arrays:
One containing your samples, say `y`. 
And another one containing [datetime](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html)s corresponding to each sample, say `x`.
Then you can use:

```
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Just as I thought. The data I have gives me time per millisecond and therefore gives me 864000 for 24:00:00:0 and 432000 for 12:00:00:0. Any idea how I can convert these to what I want?

Comment: And this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210583/is-there-a-matlab-function-to-convert-elapsed-seconds-to-hhmmss-format

Comment: When I use datestr it give me my output as a char, how can I then use this to plot as my x axis, without plotting ever single tick?